# How to use Socket.BeginReceive Overload 3?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

Hi I want to use the method `Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, SocketFlags, AsyncCallback, Object)` for an `async` server. Im just wondering how I should setup my method for the `AsyncCallback` to get the buffer.

Ive setup like this:

```
socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, size, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receive), someObject);

public void receive(IAsyncResult ar) {
    // How to get buffer?
}
```

If I add a parameter to the receive method I get an error. So how should I setup the method? There is nothing how to do that on MSDN!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the ***old*** APM programming model (Begin/End pairs)? If you're on .net4.5, use the TaskAsync API with async/await wherever possible. APM style programming is masochism in comparison.

Comment: Ill reconsider my methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state argument:

```
socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, size, SocketFlags.None, receive, buffer/*state*/);

public void receive(IAsyncResult ar) {
    // How to get buffer:
    var buffer = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;

    var bytesRead = socket.EndReceive(ar);

}
```

Comment: And that buffer will have the received data?

Comment: Hmm but I wanna send something else as the AsyncState.

Comment: Its just that the overload 3 of this method seems so useless, so im just wondering if it is or not :P

Comment: @Arbitur: Send a class which contains all variables that you need.